# Sort List<Object>

Tags: java, arraylist

```
List<Object> pairs1 = new ArrayList<Object>();

Pair p =new Pair();
p.date="2014-10-10 10:10:10";
p.no=11;    
pairs1.add(p);
```

I created a list like this; now i want to sort it using date without using  Collections.sort

Or
Show me how to get only date from list object

Comment: And what have you tried? And why do you store the date as a string instead of a `DateTime` (or `Date` if you still use Java 7-)?

Comment: Bcz in next step ia want date in string

Comment: Then what? The JDK also has an API to format a `DateTime`/`Date`

Comment: ok consider it as date and help to sort it without  Collections.sort

Comment: Questions describing your requirements and asking someone to write the code for you, explain how to write the code, or provide examples or references are off-topic. Please identify a specific problem or question about programming. Include attempted solutions, an explanation of how the results differ from the desired results, and the full text of any error messages you receive. Please read this advice on asking good questions: [[ask]], [[Writing the perfect question](http://goo.gl/UeT2tS)].

Answer (score 3):

Two ways you can do:

- Implement Comparable for your Pair class and implement compareTo method by comparing two dates and then call `Collections.sort(pairs1);`
- Create another class which implements Comparator and implement compare method and then call `Collections.sort(pairs1, mycomparator);`

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to keep the date implemented as a string and assuming `Pair` is a class you wrote yourself:

- let it implement [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)
- write a suitable implementation of `compareTo(Object o)`
- use `Collections.sort(pairs1)`